# ASP.NET Notification

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I'm developing an application in **ASP.NET** and **Postgresql(9.0)**. There will be two users of the system. Whenever the 1st user enters record into database, other user must get notified about the change in database and vice versa. Is there any control in AJAX or ASP.NET that continuously keep watch on change in database? or suggest any other way to implement such notification system.

Comment: you can have a look at signalr:http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: If you could switch to SQL Server you could start using Query Notifications: http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sql+server+query+notification&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms175110.aspx&ei=FH2OT72zEuey0QWXrczsDA&usg=AFQjCNGUW4qz_ov2b0VdmUsm2UTLgD7UFg&sig2=NAwLk8NYtFbutVf7ONZBkQ

Comment: or more specifically http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you use it from C#, but LISTEN/NOTIFY may be the solution.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-listen.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-notify.html